# Why is the Quotient Isomorphic to...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

My question is pretty simple. Why is the quotient $G/K$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$? Presumably the authors are invoking Cayley's theorem, but I can't see exactly how they are doing this. They allege that $H$ having $p$ left-cosets guarantees this, but I do not see how it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a group $G$ acts on a finite set $X$ with $n$ elements, then this action induces a homomorphism $\pi:G\to S_n$ called the permutation representation.

In this example $G$ is acting on the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, which has cardinality $[G:H]=p$. Therefore the permutation representation $\pi_H$ is a homomorphism $G\to S_p$. And since $K=\ker(\pi_H)$ by definition, it follows from the first isomorphism theorem that $G/K$ is isomorphic to the image of $\pi_H$, which is a subgroup of $S_p$.